# Pillow image resize breaking RGB colors in PNG file?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, png, image-resizing

When I use im.resize from the Pillow library, it causes unwanted artifaction where the straight alpha colors are located. It even adds colors that weren't associated with the image at all, such as the red, blue, cyan, magenta, etc. pixels.

[Before vs after using im.resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGu8e.png)

For clarification: The top part of the image is transparent. The two images above are when previewing with the alpha channel disabled.

This is snippet that emulates this issue; the original file ("trees_bg.png") is 256x219, which gets rescaled to 256x256 and resaved.

```
from PIL import Image
filename = "trees_bg.png"
im = Image.open(filename)
width, height = im.size
new_dimX = 256
new_dimY = 256
im.resize((new_dimX, new_dimY)).save(filename)
```

[Here is a link to the original picture in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4tLi.png)

Comment: Cant reproduce this behaviour. Did you rescale it multiple times ? what PIL version do you use? Where does that green background from the Before picture come from?

Comment: @tetrisprogramming 
No, the image hasn't been rescaled multiple times.
The issue still happens with Pillow 10.1.0, 9.3.0, and 8.3.1

Comment: Where does that green background from the Before picture come from?

Comment: @tetrisprogramming I'm not sure where it came from, though I do not think that it is relevant, because the problem still happens with different images.

I drew an arbitrary blob on a transparent BG in Photoshop, exported it as PNG, and ran the given script. When removing the alpha channel, the problem still persists: https://i.imgur.com/gLpbis1.png

Here's an unconverted version of the blob: https://i.imgur.com/Sb37wk1.png

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Works fine on Pillow 10.0.